# Parallelising in Python to Grab Multiple Streams

Tags: python, multiprocessing, video-streaming

I have a list of URLs of streams of CCTV cameras. I want to stream them, read their frames, and save them in a folder as I read them. I've written the following code, which works perfectly fine:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import datetime
import threading

CAMERAS_TXT_FILE_NAME = "generation/videos.txt"
CAMERAS_FOLDER_PATH_NAME = "generation/cameras"

class camThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, url):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
    def run(self):
        print("Starting " + self.name)
        camPreview(self.name, self.url)

def camPreview(name, url):
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
    while(cam.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        if ret == False:
            break
        cv2.imwrite(CAMERAS_FOLDER_PATH_NAME + "/" + name + "/" + str(datetime.datetime.now().time())+'.jpg',frame)  

#CV2 setup
cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE 

#Video Links Setup
with open(CAMERAS_TXT_FILE_NAME) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

if (not os.path.isdir(CAMERAS_FOLDER_PATH_NAME)):
        os.makedirs(CAMERAS_FOLDER_PATH_NAME)

for i in range(len(lines)):
    url = lines[i].strip()
    camName = url.split('/')[-2].split('.')[0]
    CAMERA_PATH = CAMERAS_FOLDER_PATH_NAME + "/" + camName
    if (not os.path.isdir(CAMERA_PATH)):
        os.makedirs(CAMERA_PATH)
    cam = camThread(camName, url)
    cam.start()
```

However, I realized that when the number of streams increase, the threads keep downloading the frames for the same cameras but not even starting to download other ones. I want them to save the least number of frames that they can possibly can and move on to the next frame so that most of the cameras are being downloaded rather than a small number of them being close to live.

Maybe threading is not the way to do this. Should I go for multiprocessing over the list so that they grab a number for example and go for the camera that they're given? What are the advantages and disadvantages of using multiprocessing, I am relatively new to the concepts but as fas as I understood, multiprocessing is more fitting for my case, since I don't need the processes to share a memory.

**Edit:** I researched a little bit more, I believe the most efficient way is to divide cameras between a number of processors and then use threading on them because of IO waiting times.

Answer (score 0):

It's great that you've identified the issue with the current threading implementation, and you're considering using multiprocessing. In your case, multiprocessing could indeed be a better fit, as it allows better parallelism for I/O-bound tasks like downloading frames from different camera streams.

Here are some advantages and disadvantages of using multiprocessing:

**Advantages:**

1. **Parallel Execution:** Multiprocessing allows for true parallel execution as each process runs in its own address space, which is beneficial for tasks that are I/O-bound, like downloading frames from different cameras.
2. **Isolation:** Each process has its own memory space, so there's no need to worry about shared data structures or synchronization issues. This can simplify the design and make the code more robust.
3. **Utilizes Multiple Cores:** Multiprocessing can take advantage of multiple CPU cores, leading to better overall performance on multicore systems.

**Disadvantages:**

1. **Communication Overhead:** Communication between processes can introduce some overhead. Passing data between processes requires serialization and deserialization, which can be expensive.
2. **Resource Consumption:** Each process has its own memory space, and creating too many processes can lead to increased memory consumption. It's important to manage the number of processes based on available resources.

Now, regarding your specific case, you can modify your code to use multiprocessing. Here's an example of how you might structure it:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import datetime
from multiprocessing import Process

CAMERAS_TXT_FILE_NAME = "generation/videos.txt"
CAMERAS_FOLDER_PATH_NAME = "generation/cameras"

def camPreview(name, url):
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
    while(cam.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        if ret == False:
            break
        cv2.imwrite(CAMERAS_FOLDER_PATH_NAME + "/" + name + "/" + str(datetime.datetime.now().time()) + '.jpg', frame)

def process_camera(url):
    camName = url.split('/')[-2].split('.')[0]
    CAMERA_PATH = CAMERAS_FOLDER_PATH_NAME + "/" + camName
    if not os.path.isdir(CAMERA_PATH):
        os.makedirs(CAMERA_PATH)
    camPreview(camName, url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Video Links Setup
    with open(CAMERAS_TXT_FILE_NAME) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    if not os.path.isdir(CAMERAS_FOLDER_PATH_NAME):
        os.makedirs(CAMERAS_FOLDER_PATH_NAME)

    processes = []

    for i in range(len(lines)):
        url = lines[i].strip()
        process = Process(target=process_camera, args=(url,))
        processes.append(process)
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

This code uses the `multiprocessing.Process` class to create separate processes for each camera stream. Each process runs the `process_camera` function, which in turn runs the `camPreview` function for that specific camera stream.

Comment: Thanks for chatGPT answer but I have a question, if I have more cameras than the processors I have then this won't probably work. So, that part should probably be changed and fixed so that I create at most the number of processors I have.